# How to I Document User Rights on an existing Linux System?

Tags: linux, command-line, permissions, user-accounts, documentation

Need to document user rights on an existing Linux system.

What commands, actions, etc. will allow me to gather complete user profiles?

**User rights include, but are not limited to:**

  File/Directory: Read, Write, Execute, and Delete

  Access: Root, su, sudo

  Groups/Roles: wheel

  Connections: Local, Remote

**User types include, but are not limited to:** Anonymous, Authenticated, System

**________**

**UPDATE (1):**

  System_Output based on right: Permission denied

  Commands: getent group, getfacl, visudo /etc/sudoers

  Keywords_to_add_to_Searches: "man page", apropos

  Keywords: Access Control List (ACL)

**UPDATE (2):**

  As root, how would I document user rights. Example: [cd /home] [ls] [getfacl _user_01_to_n_] [visudo /etc/sudoers] ... etc.

**UPDATE (3):**

  Tools:
  [ACLbit – ACL Backup and Inspect Tool](http://aclbit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Sounds like homework to me?

Comment: @BloodPhilia -- No, it's not hw. It's a real self-assigned project task to attempt to make managing an existing system possible. And the question was written from scratch based on my limited understand of how Linux controls user rights.

Comment: Okay! Just looked like it then =)

Comment: @BloodPhilia - np, took it as a compliment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `getfacl(1)` man page. It's part of `acl` package. Prints file access control lists. On filesystems without ACLs  it lists traditional unix permissions.

**Edit**

Look at various options of `getfacl` for instance, to document permissions of user `joe` you could say:

```
getfacl -R -p /home/joe > joe_permissions.txt
```

(output of `getfacl` will be redirected to a `joe_permissions.txt` file)

Comment: A little explanation as to what is does would be proper. Just a reference is not answering a question...

Comment: man and apropos will tell you. :) .

Comment: @Casual_Coder - Thanks, getfacl is a on topic command, and also lead to me finding the keyword "Access Control List (ACL)"

Comment: @Casual_Coder - Thanks, the additional info, here's the best round up on Linux ACL I've found: http://www.suse.de/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/